# What delete rule should I use in a playlist entity?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In my data model, I have a playlist entity that has a to-many relationship to items in the playlist and an inverse relationship.

When the playlist is deleted, I want all te stuff in it to be deleted, so I use the Cascade delete rule. When an item in the playlist is deleted, well, just delete the item. Which rule should I use?

I'll illustrate this.

First, the managed objects look like this

```
Playlist 1
items: a, b, c

Playlist 2
items: d

item a
playlist: 1

item b
playlist: 1

item c
playlist: 1

item d
playlist: 2
```

If I delete Playlist 1, it will look like this:

```
Playlist 2
items: d

item d
playlist: 2
```

If I delete d, it will look like this

```
Playlist 1
items: a, b, c

Playlist 2
items: 

item a
playlist: 1

item b
playlist: 1

item c
playlist: 1
```

From the docs, I don't know which rule to use for the inverse relationship.

- Deny: item will only be deleted if it does not have a playlist. But an item will always have a playlist because of the cascade rule in the to-many relationship
- Nullify: This only removes the relationship between the playlist and the item, but not delete the item. I want the item to be deleted.
- Cascade: Obviously I don't want the playlist to be deleted when I delete the item
- No Action: This will cause the item to be deleted, but the playlist's `items` property will still hold a reference to that item.

I think I must have misunderstood one of these rules. There must be one that I can use, right?

Note: This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796460/core-data-inverse-delete-rules-which-one-should-i-apply) because that OP wants the Manager to be also deleted when it has no employees. But I want to still keep the playlist when all the items in it are deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delete rule refers to the target of the relationship and says "what do I do to related objects when *this object is deleted*". Your `item` is going to be deleted no matter what, since that is what you are doing. The only rule that prevents the `item` being deleted is `deny`

In the case of the inverse relationship from the `item` to the `playlist` you want `nullify` since this will remove the reference from the playlist to the item.

Comment: But if I use nullify and delete lots of objects, they will still be in the hard disk, right? And they will probably occupy lots of space if I deleted lots of them. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You are misunderstanding. It is the forward reference from the playlist to the item that will be nullified (as the item no longer exists). The item will be deleted

Comment: I understand now. So it works kind of like ARC, right? When the reference is set to null, the object is automatically garbage collected.

Comment: No.  You are specifically deleting the item, so Core Data needs to decide what to do with the referenced playlist. It can delete it, deny the delete, do nothing or nullify its reference to the deleted item.

Comment: Ok I see. Thank you!